# Error due to NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jsoup

Class test

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String  url, artistIn, artist, base;
        SongUrl[] obj = new SongUrl[100];
        base = "http://lyrics.wikia.com/";
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter an artist");
        artistIn = in.nextLine();
        artist = artistIn.replace(' ', '_');
        url = "http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?func=getSong&artist=" + artist + "&fmt=html";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements a = doc.select("a[href]");
        for(Element alink : a){
            obj[count] = new SongUrl();
            obj[count].urlSong = alink.toString();
            count++;
            obj[count].serialNo = count;      //Faced NPE on this line
            System.out.println(count + " " + alink.html());
        }
    }
}
```

Class SongUrl

```
public class SongUrl {
    int serialNo;
    String urlSong;
}
```

I was faced with NullPointerException on the line
`obj[count].serialNo = count;` . It's surprising that if NPE was to occur, it should have happened on this line `obj[count].urlSong = alink.toString();` which came before it. I'm in the dark as to what has gone wrong.

Comment: You incremented `count` between those two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have increased the `count` and now it's pointing to next item from the array that is `null`

```
  obj[count].urlSong = alink.toString();
  count++;                      // this is causing the issue
  obj[count].serialNo = count;  // obj[count] is null
```

Increment the `count` in the end of the for loop.

---

I suggest you to initialize just below the declaration to avoid such `NullPointerException`

```
 SongUrl[] obj = new SongUrl[100];
 for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
        obj[i] = new SongUrl();
 }
```

Better to use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Keep the member `private` and use getter & setter methods. Read more about [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

```
public class SongUrl {
    private int serialNo;
    private String urlSong;
    // getter & setter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You increment `count` before setting the `serialNo` - since this index of the array is not initialized yet, you're getting a `NullPointerException`. To avoid this, you should increment `count` last:

```
obj[count] = new SongUrl();
obj[count].urlSong = alink.toString();
obj[count].serialNo = count + 1; // Note the +1 - count is incremented afterwards
count++;
```